# Converting from a List to a Dictionary, trouble with foreach statement

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I started poking at switching a list structure over to a dictionary and i'm having some trouble. I'm in the middle of modifying my foreach statement `foreach (KeyValuePair <int, Player> p in players)` to work with my dictionary but I'm having difficulty in understanding how I then go about accessing variables in my player object using the key value pair.

And I'm currenty stuck on this line using a dictionary : `moveMsg += p.connectionId.ToString() + '%' + p.playerPosition.x.ToString() + '%' + p.playerPosition.y.ToString() + '|';`

The error I'm getting is: `Assets/Scripts/Server.cs(118,18): error CS1061: Type System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Player>' does not contain a definition for connectionId' and no extension method connectionId' of type System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Player>' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

How do I make the modification?

Declare dictionary: `public Dictionary<int, Player> players = new Dictionary<int, Player>();`

Dictionary

```
// Ask player for their position

if (Time.time - lastMovementUpdate > movementUpdateRate)
{
    lastMovementUpdate = Time.time;
    string moveMsg = "ASKPOSITION|";
    foreach (KeyValuePair <int, Player> p in players)
        moveMsg += p.connectionId.ToString() + '%' + p.playerPosition.x.ToString() + '%' + p.playerPosition.y.ToString() + '|';
    moveMsg = moveMsg.Trim('|');
    Send(moveMsg, unreliableChannel, players);
}
```

Player class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player
{
    public string PlayerName;
    public GameObject Avatar;
    public int ConnectionId;
    public byte[] Tex;          // data coming from CanvasController
    public string Type;         // data coming from CanvasController
    public string Id;           // data coming from GameManager
    public int Strength;        // data coming from PlayerController
    public int Hitpoints;       // data coming from PlayerController
    public bool IsAlive;        // data coming from PlayerController

    // Initial method takes base arguments for testing
    public Player(string playerName, GameObject avatar, int connectionID)
    {
        PlayerName = playerName;
        Avatar = avatar;
        ConnectionId = connectionID;
    }
    // Overload method takes all animal arguments
    public Player(string playerName, GameObject avatar, int connectionID, byte[] tex, string type, string id, int strength, int hitpoints, bool isAlive)
    {
        PlayerName = playerName;
        Avatar = avatar;
        ConnectionId = connectionID;

        Tex = tex;
        Type = type;
        Id = id;
        Strength = strength;
        Hitpoints = hitpoints;
        IsAlive = isAlive;

        Debug.Log(id + " : " + type + " created with strength " + strength + ", hit points " + hitpoints + ", and a texture the size of " + tex.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your variable `p` is a `KeyValuePair<int, Player>` you can not access to `ConnectionId` directly with `p.ConnectionId`. You should access it with `p.Value.ConnectionId`, because in an `<int, Player>` KeyValuePair, Player corresponds to the Value. You can also access to the key in a [similar fashion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224761(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

KeyPairValue contains only two properties Key and Value

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx

Did you try with:
`p.Key` instead of `p.ConnectionId` and 
`p.Value` instead of of `p.PlayerPosition`

Edit: I wrote a small lambda to simply your code using the Aggregate fct. I pass the default value and then for each items in your dict, it will concact another string. I also use string Interpolation to avoid string concatenation ($"{variable}").

```
    class Player
    {
        public Point Position { get; set; }
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var players = new Dictionary<int, Player>();
        var msg = players.Aggregate(
              string.Empty, 
             (current, p) => current + 
                       $"{p.Key}%{p.Value.Position.X}%{p.Value.Position.Y}|");
    }
```

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure you could convert your foreach loop to a nice lambda expression. I will give you more details tmr

Comment: It seems you are missing the PlayPosition property as well

Answer (score 1):

You have a ConnectionId in yr Player class, but access to connectionId.
PS. Strangely why its compiled.
Btw, you may use players.Join - a linq extension